# Como encolher uma query grande - Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, query

No Visual Studio, temos a possibilidade de encolher um código grande, ou seja, visualmente diminuir o tamanho, como forma de facilitar a leitura, exemplo:

```
#region

Seu código aqui...

#endregion
```

Gostaria de fazer o mesmo em uma query dentro do meu PGAdmin.
É possível?

Answer (score 1):

Cara, infelizmente não. As querys muitas vezes tem centenas ou até mesmo milhares de linhas, vai depender do tamanho do banco de dados. São arquivos realmente grandes. Em Postgres você pode organizar melhor as querys usando uma ou várias CTE's (Common Table Expression)

```
WITH cte AS (
         SELECT 
           tabela1.coluna1, 
           tabela1.coluna2, 
           tabela1.coluna3 
         FROM 
           schema1.tabela1
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

A CTE é uma tabela temporária que existe somente durante a execução da query.

Reduzir o tamanho em si é impossível, mas da pra "quebrar" em pedaços menores para auxiliar tanto na leitura quanto na execução.